# access dictionary for use within a countdown in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, swift, timer

I have a working countdown which you can increase by pushing the add button and thats what the time counts down from (so basically a user can set the countdown)

I would like to display the starting time as 00:00 as it does in my label.

When I click button to increase the countdown it just begins at 1 obviously because at the moment its just an Int

So i had a thought of create a dictionary something like this

```
var timeDictionary : [Double : Double] = [00 : 00]
```

I just want to increase to 00:01, 2, 3 when the + button is pressed and start from 00:00. Can anyone help with this if possible please?

this is my full code for the countdown

```
var timeDictionary : [Double : Double] =  [00 : 00]


var timer = NSTimer()
var countdown = 0

func runTimer() {


    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, 

       selector:Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func updateTimer() {

    if countdown > 0 {

        countdown--
        TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)

        } else {

           countdown = 0
             TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)

    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var TimerLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func IncreaseCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

    countdown++
    TimerLabel.text = String(countdown)


}


@IBAction func StartCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

    runTimer()

}


@IBAction func StopCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't want a dictionary (hint read what a dictionary is) - You could use an array with two elements (hours and minutes) or simply two variables for hours and minutes

Comment: thanks, do you have any examples of your answer obviously I know how to create an array but refferencing it in a counter and allowing the user to increment this value im struggling witht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to format the counter as you display it -

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

var timer = NSTimer()
var countdown = 0

func runTimer() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector:Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func updateTimer() {

    if --countdown < 1 {
        timer.invalidate()
        countdown=0;
    }

    self.updateTimerLabel();    
}  

@IBAction func IncreaseCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {
    countdown++
    self.updateTimerLabel()
}


@IBAction func StartCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {
    runTimer()
}


@IBAction func StopCountdown(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

func updateTimerLabel() {

    TimerLabel.text =NSString(format:"%02d:%02d",seconds/60,seconds%60)
}

}
```

Note that I also changed `TimerLabel` to `timerLabel` as the convention is that variables should start with a lowercase letter

Comment: Yes, I didn't really think about what you were trying to achieve when I added my comment yesterday, I just answered the question about dictionaries.  Once I started to write the code the correct answer was obvious